If I have Ashaya out and return Quirion Ranger with itself, can it target itself?
If I have Lotus Cobra, Ashaya, Soul of the Wild, Nadu, Winged Wisdom, and Quirion Ranger out, can I target Quirion Ranger with its own ability while returning Qurion Ranger to my hand?

Yes, the combo works. Quirion Ranger sees itself being targeted and thus triggers the ability granted by Nadu.
A creature can target itself with its own ability, even if payment for that ability causes that creature to change zones. See for example here.
The other question would be, does the ability granted by Nadu trigger? The answer is also "yes". Since Quirion Ranger's activated ability requires a target, it only goes on the stack if all its chosen targets are legal during the ability activation process, which is identical to the spellcasting process for the relevant parts.

601.2c The player announces their choice of an appropriate object or player for each target the spell requires. [..]

If Quirion Ranger was not a legal choice of targets, the game state would return to just before the ability activation was announced:

601.2e The game checks to see if the proposed spell can legally be cast. If the proposed spell is illegal, the game returns to the moment before the casting of that spell was proposed (see rule 730, “Handling Illegal Actions”).

If it is a legal choice, however, that means Quirion Ranger has been successfully targeted, and Nardu's ability triggers now.

603.2. Whenever a game event or game state matches a triggered ability’s trigger event, that ability automatically triggers. The ability doesn’t do anything at this point.

It will wait to enter the stack until after the currently activating ability has gone on the stack.

603.3. Once an ability has triggered, its controller puts it on the stack as an object that’s not a card the next time a player would receive priority.

The process continues to paying the ability's cost; only now does the Quirion Ranger return to hand and the activated ability goes on the stack:

601.2f The player determines the total cost of the spell.


601.2h The player pays the total cost.  [..]


601.2i Once the steps described in 601.2a–h are completed, effects that modify the characteristics of the spell as it’s cast are applied, then the spell becomes cast. Any abilities that trigger when a spell is cast or put onto the stack trigger at this time. If the spell’s controller had priority before casting it, they get priority.

Now Nadu's ability goes on the stack. When it resolves, it does not matter that the Quirion Ranger is no longer on the battlefield. Nadu's ability is not targeted. It exists independently of and does not require any information about its source.
You may then recast Quirion Ranger, get your Lotus Cobra trigger, and repeat the combo indefinitely.

Yes, that works fine. When activating abilities, you choose targets before paying costs, so Quirion Ranger is still on the battlefield while you are choosing targets, which means that it is a valid target.
However, it's not entirely clear whether doing that will trigger the ability granted by Nadu. I can't find any rule or ruling that establishes when exactly a triggered ability with a condition like "Whenever (something) becomes the target of a spell or ability..." triggers. The problem is that if an ability like that triggers only after costs are paid, then I think it wouldn't trigger in this situation, because the ability wouldn't exist at that time.

As judge, I would rule that it would trigger. This is similar to how death triggers still work when there is a board wipe, even though the creature with the triggered abilility is already in the graveyard when the trigger. As long as the condition is met at some point, the trigger will be put on stack the next time a player would get priority.

Death triggers are explicitly in the category of triggers that look back in time to before the triggering event to determine whether any abilities need to trigger. See rule 603.10 for more information. However, the ability granted by Nadu is not in that category, so the same logic doesn't apply.
